# Mock.Arrange what does it actually do?

Tags: c#, justmock

I am new to testing and new to JustMock.

I have written my first test.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckifExportToCSVIsSuccessfull()
    {
        C1FlexGrid c1flexGrid = new C1FlexGrid();
        
        C1FlexGridBase c1flexGridBase = (C1FlexGridBase)(c1flexGrid);

        Timeslice.ComponentOneExtensions.C1FlexGridExtensions.ExportResult expected = Timeslice.ComponentOneExtensions.C1FlexGridExtensions.ExportResult.Succeeded;

        Mock.Arrange(() => c1flexGridBase.ExportToCSV($"")).Returns(Timeslice.ComponentOneExtensions.C1FlexGridExtensions.ExportResult.Failed);

        // Assert 
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, c1flexGridBase.ExportToCSV($""));
    }
```

Here is the function it is testing.

```
     public static ExportResult ExportToCSV(this C1FlexGridBase c1FlexGrid, string fileName)
    {
        c1FlexGrid.SaveGrid(fileName, FileFormatEnum.TextComma, FileFlags.IncludeFixedCells);
        return ExportResult.Succeeded;
    }
```

The test works as it is failing.

I don't understand what the Arrange is supposed to do.

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/justmock/getting-started/mock#arrange

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, you hadn't tagged your question with `[justmock]` and I'd skimmed over it reading your question. I've added the tag for you and found the appropriate documentation.

Comment: I did read the doc that's how I got this far. I just can't understand what the Arrange is actually doing.

Comment: If I'm reading it right, you're replacing the `ExportToCSV` method. Presumably for a blank filename, it will return Failed as you've instructed.